# Why not declaring a variable as an argument of a function?

Tags: javascript, variable-declaration

I don't see that in any shorthand technique or stackOverflow questions..then I wonder if the following can be a shorthand technique.

Imagine I have a function which I know there is exactly 1 argument that will be passed to it :

```
function myFunc(arr) {
  var i;
  for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
    if(arr[i] === 3) {return true;}
  }
}
```

Is it a good practice in that case to write :

```
function myFunc(arr, i) {
  for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
    if(arr[i] === 3) {return true;}
  }
}
```

I know that in most case we only save 4 bytes and this represent a very small improvement but sometimes for a short function it can be more readable without wasting 1/2 lines just to declare variables.

Edit: also I want to declare i in the scope of the function and not in the `for` loop sinc I want to be able to reuse it.

Comment: It isn't good practice to change the signature of a method solely so you can save a few bytes inside the method.  There's no reason to pass in `i`.

Comment: that has `for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ )` too

Comment: How has this "saved 4 bytes"?  Why would you want the function to require that a variable which is only ever known or used internally be provided to the function from an external source?  It's not clear what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: "it can be more readable" — I'd say *less* readable.

Comment: @NathanK no effect he will be initializing

Comment: Let that kind of optimization to be done by minification/bundling tools and keep your code more readable. :)

Comment: Also, the less arguments you have, the better. You make development cleaner, and you reduce dependencies on the calling method.

Comment: This is quite confusing technique in terms of your function beings used by someone else...

Comment: 4 bytes vs 200 bytes of comment.

Comment: If the raw byte count of your source code is becoming a problem, this is not the kind of optimization you should be looking for.

Comment: `var ` vs `, i` - so you save just one symbol. do you really need it?

Comment: Ok, thanks for your comments, from what I can understand, this is **not** a good practice, but this is also not such a bad thing if I am the only one to develop the script...

Answer (score 1):

You would only do this if you were going to actually use `i` in the `for` loop.

e.g:

```
function myFunc(arr, i) {
    for(i; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        arr[i];
    }
}

// Why you would do this though, is another matter (and bizarre)
myFunc(anArray, 9);
```

Instead, it would be better to do:

```
function myFunc(arr) {
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++ ) {
        arr[i];
    }
}
```

and not worry about 4 bytes...

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, You're true about the `for(var i = 0;...` but I prefer to declare it in the scope of function (maybe I could have chosen a better example) in case if I want to reuse it after...

Comment: When using a loop counter, you'll unlikely be using it outside of that loop in most cases.

Comment: yes, sure, but i could want to reuse i for another `for` loop or even for another purpose, just to store some temporary data...but anyway, thanks, this can be a solution.

Comment: @SébastienGarcia-Roméo, with `var` you could reuse `i` after loop

Comment: @Grundy ah...ok, apologies :)